# How to properly dock right more than one element, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, docking, dockpanel

I don't know why when I dock right the last Control doesn't dock properly. Here is my DockPanel example:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="A" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="B" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="C" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
</DockPanel>
```

In this example "C" button isn't docked properly.
Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a property called `LastChildFill` that was given the wrong default. Set it to false:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False"> 
    <Button Content="A" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="B" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="C" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you! The last child element within a DockPanel stretches to fill the remaining available space (MSDN).